# Proving a function cannot be approximated by other functions

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway book that I am stuck at. Here I think $G_1$ is contained in $G$. I am required to use the Runge's approximation theorem to solve it. I first thought of the function $1/z$ defined in the punctured disc but $K$ is a compact subset of $G$ so I think $1/z$ can be approximated on $K$ by functions in $H(G)$. Could anyone please help me how to show that such $f$ exists?

Comment: What is $H(G)$?

Comment: It is the set of holomorphic functions on $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(z)=\frac1z$, defined on $B(0;1)\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: But on $K$, can't $f$ be approximated by holomorphic functions on the unit disc?

Comment: @Keith No. Let $\gamma(t)=\frac34e^{it}$ ($t\in[0,2\pi]$). Then $\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i$. But, for each $g\in H(G)$, $\int_\gamma g(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$.